# Matplotlib Slider does not update the scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a collection of points that (according to the model) move over time. There are 2d lists X and Y, where i-th element of each list is also a list containing respective coordinates of points.

```py
fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
scat = plt.scatter(self.X[i], self.Y[i])

axslider = plt.axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.775, 0.05])
slider = Slider(ax=axslider, label='', valmin=1, valmax=n, valinit=1, valstep=1)
def update(val):
    i = int(slider.val)
    scat.set_offsets(self.X[i], self.Y[i])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
slider.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

This code does not update the scatter every time I toggle the slider. It executes and the figures are shown, however, the interpreter also shows an error:

> TypeError: set_offsets() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Does anybody see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the fine docs

```
>>> help(sc.set_offsets)
Help on method set_offsets in module matplotlib.collections:

set_offsets(offsets) method of matplotlib.collections.PathCollection instance
    Set the offsets for the collection.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    offsets : (N, 2) or (2,) array-like
```

This means that you need to pass a SINGLE array (or list) that has `N` rows and 2 columns, e.g., `[[x0, y0], [x1, y1], ..., [xn, yn]]`.

You can arrange your data in this configuration using [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy-stack)

```
scat.set_offsets(np.stack((self.X[i], self.Y[i]), axis=1)
```

or [`np.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html#numpy-c)

```
scat.set_offsets(np.c_[self.X[i], self.Y[i]])
```